# ASP.NET MVC Custom Authorization : AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, roles

I'm following this tutorial [link](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2009/02/17/custom-authorization-with-aspnet-mvc/)

I have a table **users** {*iduser, user, pass, role*}

I'm using this users : `string[] users = db.users.Select(t => t.user).ToArray();`

instead of : `string[] users = Users.Split(',');` Is it ok ?

My problem is with roles : `SiteRoles role = (SiteRoles)httpContext.Session["role"];`

Q: Where do I store the role for my user ?

My simplified account controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        HeliosEntities db = new HeliosEntities();       
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            bool userok = db.users.Any(t => t.user == model.UserName && t.pass == model.Password);
            if (userok == true) 
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorect password or user!");
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the default membership provider? Also, it looks like your not using encryption for your password, this will open up many security holes.

Comment: I followed this 5 part tutorial : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXfhPj1rlQ8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at your link above shows that it is getting the user's role from session:

```
(SiteRoles)httpContext.Session["role"];
```

so you need to set the session value when the user logs in, for example:

```
var userRole = Roles.Admin | Roles.User;
httpContext.Session["role"] = role;
```

I don't know where you store the information about what role the user is in though.

Comment: The information about the role and user is stored in the *users* entity(EF).  Where do I set the session value, in my home-madeAccountController ?(see youtube link above)

Comment: When the user successfully logs in, you fetch their roles from the database and set the session value at that point.

Comment: Is it ok how I populated the Users in the CustomAuthorizeAttribute class ?

Comment: I'm using this users : string[] users = db.users.Select(t => t.user).ToArray();

instead of : string[] users = Users.Split(','); Is it ok ?

Comment: I have another problem with remembering my role : when I refresh the page I get (Object reference not set to an instance of an object. - HeliosRoles role = (HeliosRoles)httpContext.Session["role"];) . In AccountController at login I get the role from : int rolqry = db.users.Where(t => t.user == model.UserName && t.pass == model.Password).Select(t => t.type).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Are you definitely storing the role in the Session like so: httpContext.Session["role"] = role;